# How do I wash flexible cutting boards and silicone baking sheets?

Tags: cleaning

Flexible tools like thin cutting boards and silicone baking sheets are wonderful to use, but I hate cleaning them. They don't hold their form well enough to wash by hand OR set in the dishwasher. I resort to setting them on something firm first, which I then have to wash additionally afterwards.

Tell me there's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There has been no problem laying them flat on the top rack of a dishwasher. The water spray may move them around, or rarely fold them over so rewashing is needed, but no harm is done.

Comment: Over the top of all my cups and mugs you mean?

Comment: Without other items is best... if the mat covers something, that item won't get washed well.

Comment: the mat would take up MOST of my top rack. I'd practically have to run a cycle just for one mat?